# Extract XML element value from a RSS feed

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, rss, casperjs

I have a RSS feed and I need to extract the latest pubDate element from it for my test. What is the best way to do the same ?

RSS Feed link: https://secure.hyper-reach.com/rss/310085

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <atom:link href="https://secure.hyper-reach.com/rss/310085" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link>https://secure.hyper-reach.com/rss/310085</link>
        <title>Hyper-Reach Automated Test Account alerts feed "Automated RSS Test"</title>
        <description>Constant feed of alerts from Automated Test Account via hyper-reach.com</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 21 Nov 2014 00:56:15 -0500</lastBuildDate>
        <language>null</language>
        <ttl>5</ttl>
        <item>
            <title>Alert (2014-11-21)</title>
            <pubDate>Fri, 21 Nov 2014 00:56:15 -0500</pubDate>
            <description>This is a test message.</description>
            <link>https://secure.hyper-reach.com/servlet/getprompt?prompt_id=122967&amp;ver=0&amp;format=34&amp;nologin=1</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">https://secure.hyper-reach.com/rss/item/257029</guid>
        </item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

What I am doing:

```
checkRSSFeed = function() {
    //first I navigate to a certain page in my website
    var href = '';

    casper.then(function() {
        this.test.assertExists(x('//a[contains(@href, "SUBSTRING OF URL")]'), 'the element exists');
        href = casper.getElementAttribute(x('//a[contains(@href, "SUBSTRING OF URL")]'), 'href');
     }).then(function() {
        this.open(href);
     }).then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());

        var pubDate = '';
        this.getPageContent();
        pubDate = this._utils_.getElementByXPath('.//pubDate');
     });
};
```

The error I am getting is

> `uncaughtError: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this._utils_.getElementByXPath')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the `pubDate` content you can use the [`casper.fetchText`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fetchtext) function, but it has a drawback that it concatenates all text nodes into one string:

```js
casper.echo(casper.fetchText("pubDate"));
```

would print

> Fri, 21 Nov 2014 00:56:15 -0500Fri, 21 Nov 2014 00:47:34 -0500Fri, 21 Nov 2014 00:45:36 -0500

To actually retrieve the text separately you can use [`casper.getElementsInfo`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) which works on multiple elements and provides the `text` property. A simple mapping afterwards generates an array that you can work on afterwards:

```js
var pubDates = casper.getElementsInfo("pubDate").map(function(elementInfo){
    return elementInfo.text; // or even `return new Date(elementInfo.text)`
});
```

But since you only want the latest one and RSS feed are sorted newest to oldest, you can simply use the first one (note the lack of an `s` in `getElementInfo`):

```js
var pubDate = casper.getElementInfo("pubDate").text;
```

You previous approach would have worked, if you would have done this in the page context. The clientutils module is only accessible in the page context (inside `casper.evaluate`).

```js
var pubDate = this.evaluate(function(){
    return __utils__.getElementByXPath('//pubDate').innerText;
});
```

Note that `__utils__` has two underscores on both sides. Also you cannot pass DOM elements from page context out to casper context, but you can pass strings and other primitive objects. Therefore I returned the `innerText` property of the DOM element. The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) says this:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.